# Android: why material components don't fit different screens?

Tags: android, layout, material-design

I have a layout and I want all its components to fit every possible screen resolution but it doesn't. Looks as expected on Pixel 2, though.

`layout.xml`, every constant defined in `dp`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_name_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_first_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/last_name_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_last_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/last_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/preferred_name_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_pref_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/preferred_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_number_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_phone_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_email">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_password"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_confirmation_layout"
            style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:hint="@string/sign_up_password_confirmation"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_confirmation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/default_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_button_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="@string/wizard_sign_up_submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

From left to right:

- [Pixel 3, 5.46", 1080 x 2160: 440dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaNhV.png);
- [Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, 5.1", 1440 x 2560: 577dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnqCu.png);
- [Nexus 5, 4.95", 1080 x 1920: xxhdpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smaFg.png)

Answer (score 1):

> An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This
>   size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers
>   with supporting multiple screens.

I would like to suggest you that you use **[sdp (scalable dp)](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)**

Example

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
```

To add sdp to your project

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

**FYI**

Read **[Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)** .

> The best way to create a responsive layout for different screen sizes
>   is to use ConstraintLayout as the base layout in your UI.
>   ConstraintLayout allows you to specify the position and size for each
>   view according to spatial relationships with other views in the
>   layout. This way, all the views can move and stretch together as the
>   screen size changes.

Comment: Have the same result when set ConstraintLayout as base layout. Sdp doesn't help either. Every screen still shows this (and some other) layout differently on different phones.

Comment: @VictorK. Did you set Constraint Layout in `layout.xml` section?

Comment: It is the root element of a layout. The first element that contains everything.

Comment: Alright, that seems to work if you define the bottom constraint.

Comment: Generally it seems to work even if the root element is `<layout>` but in my setup something goes wrong and I can't figure out what. Anyway, thanks.